# How can I format an element in array (json format) which its name has special characters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I'm trying to pass some header on the request on one of them contains special character.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

This header is required to allow the request go forward and dont be block by CORS

Code:

```
const getData = async (fileType) => {
  try {
    let apiName = "Dev";
    let path = "/listfiles";
    let myInit = {
      headers: {
        Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"
        filetype: fileType,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${(await Auth.currentSession())
          .getIdToken()
          .getJwtToken()}`,
      },
    };
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
Line 73:19:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","

71 |         let myInit = {
72 |           headers: {
> 73 |             Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*",
 |                   ^
74 |             filetype: fileType,
75 |             Authorization: `Bearer ${(await Auth.currentSession())
76 |               .getIdToken()
```

Comment: I think you just forgot a comma and some quote, `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", `

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `-` for object keys without quotes. And I think you forgot a comma

```js
const getData = async (fileType) => {
  try {
    let apiName = "Dev";
    let path = "/listfiles";
    let myInit = {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        filetype: fileType,
        Authorization: `Bearer ${(await Auth.currentSession())
          .getIdToken()
          .getJwtToken()}`,
      },
    };
```

Comment: "," is fine I've just forget to add it to the question. "-" is why it give me the error. Is there anyway to name object keys with special character like "-"

Comment: You have to add quotes to the object key. Check the answer